# Ping to any ip does not work on ppp0 from USB 3G modem Huawei using wvdial

Tags: networking, ping, pppd, wvdial

I have a Debian OS on a Banana pi and I use a Huawei 3G modem to connect to the internet from it using the wvdial tool. I also have the usb-modeswitch installed and I think the modem is working as a modem correctly.

The existing setup was working correctly for a few months until I decided to turn off the banana pi and left it for about 3 months and now when I try to connect to the internet using the same settings it is not working.

I am able to connect to the internet carrier but cant use the internet.

When I type **ping 8.8.8.8** or **ping -I ppp0 8.8.8.8** it does not respond anything and returns:

```
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
194 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 193000ms
```

my **wvdial.conf** looks like this:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.unite.md"
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Studpi Mode = 1
Baud = 9600
New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
ISDN = 0
Phone = *99#
Username = tmn
Password = tmn
```

when I run **sudo wvdial** I get:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.unite.md"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.unite.md"
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
CONNECT
--> Carrier detected.  Waiting for prompt.
--> Don't know what to do!  Starting pppd and hoping for the best.
--> Starting pppd at Mon Jan  1 15:55:48 2018
--> Pid of pppd: 4608
--> Using interface ppp0
--> pppd: x▒[02]
--> pppd: x▒[02]
--> pppd: x▒[02]
--> pppd: x▒[02]
--> pppd: x▒[02]
--> local  IP address 100.68.71.79
--> pppd: x▒[02]
--> remote IP address 10.64.64.64
--> pppd: x▒[02]
--> primary   DNS address 172.26.134.20
--> pppd: x▒[02]
--> secondary DNS address 172.26.135.24
--> pppd: x▒[02]
```

so it looks like it is connecting correctly to the ip 100.68.71.79

And when I do a **ping 100.68.71.79** it works correctly. But on any other addresses the ping is not working.

I have checked the modem with the same sim on my windows and it was able to connect and surf the internet.

Here is output of **sudo ifconfig**

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
          inet addr:100.68.71.79  P-t-P:10.64.64.64  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1440  Metric:1
          RX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1245 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
          RX bytes:186 (186.0 B)  TX bytes:64913 (63.3 KiB)
```

Output of **sudo iptables -L**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Output of **sudo route**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         100.68.71.79    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
10.64.64.64     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

here is the **pppd** info from /var/log/syslog

```
Jan  1 16:00:22 localhost kernel: [10908.423138] option 1-1.2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Jan  1 16:00:22 localhost kernel: [10908.424115] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to 

ttyUSB0
Jan  1 16:00:22 localhost kernel: [10908.424991] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jan  1 16:00:22 localhost kernel: [10908.425947] option 1-1.2:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Jan  1 16:00:22 localhost kernel: [10908.426722] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to 

ttyUSB1
Jan  1 16:00:22 localhost kernel: [10908.427401] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jan  1 16:00:22 localhost kernel: [10908.428406] option 1-1.2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Jan  1 16:00:22 localhost kernel: [10908.429176] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to 

ttyUSB2
Jan  1 16:01:02 localhost pppd[4764]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jan  1 16:01:02 localhost pppd[4764]: Using interface ppp0
Jan  1 16:01:02 localhost pppd[4764]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB0
Jan  1 16:01:02 localhost pppd[4764]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jan  1 16:01:02 localhost pppd[4764]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jan  1 16:01:07 localhost pppd[4764]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Jan  1 16:01:07 localhost pppd[4764]: local  IP address 100.68.71.79
Jan  1 16:01:07 localhost pppd[4764]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Jan  1 16:01:07 localhost pppd[4764]: primary   DNS address 172.26.134.20
Jan  1 16:01:07 localhost pppd[4764]: secondary DNS address 172.26.135.24
```